# jQuery live() - functionality loss - live() without click: but on enter key?

Tags: jquery

I have a question regarding jQuery's live() function.

I am programming a forum. As soon as someone posts something and hits enter, jQuery appends the other posts and also inserts a textarea for comments, to which the following event handler applies:

```
//Comment on a post
$('.commenttext').keyup(function(e) {
    if (((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
    }
});
```

The function to post a comment is then called - well at least it should be. For the old posts it works fine, but not for the one that was just posted and appended.

I know that it is possible to preserve functionality using the live() function. However, as you can see, the post gets submitted when hitting enter, there is no button involved. So I wonder how to combine these things, i.e. using live() but without click: ?

FYI, the function to post something looks like this:

```
//Function to post
function post()
{
    //Get posttext and preserve line breaks
    var posttext=$('#posttext').val();

    //Ajax if posttext is not empty
    if(posttext!="")
    {
        $.ajax({
            //blablabla
            success: function(postid){

                //Prepend posts with the new post
                var newpost=posttext+'<br/><textarea id="commenttext'+postid+'" class="commenttext" placeholder=" Comment..."></textarea>';
                $(newpost).hide().prependTo('#postsDiv').fadeIn('slow');

            }
        });
    }
}
```

UPDATE 1:

I have changed the event handler to post something to this, which posts fine, but still the functionality is not there:

```
//Post something
$('#postDiv').on('keyup', '#posttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        post($(this));
    }
});
```

UPDATE 2:

It works for now :) I didn't know both comment() and post() have to be live.
I now have the following two functions:

```
//Post something
$('#postDiv').on('keyup', '#posttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        post($(this));
    }
});
```

and

```
//Comment on a post
$('.commenttext').live('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
    }
});
```

It works fine, but it would be better to also use on() to comment. I have tried this:

```
$('.commentsDiv').on('keyup', '.commenttext', function(e) {
    if ((e.which == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        post($(this));
    }
});
```

but it doesn't work - how come? commentsDiv is the parent element of commenttext, which is the  comment textarea. Do I need to address it with an id?

Thanks :)

Comment: FYI, jQuery already normalizes the event object so there is no need for `(e.keyCode || e.which)`. Just use `e.which`. More at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: You can try `$(document).on('keyup', '.commenttext', function(e) {`

Comment: @Rocket thank you, the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) can be used with any event you want, not just `click` (even custom events).

```
$('.commenttext').live('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
    }
});
```

NOTE: If you are using jQuery 1.7+, you should no longer use `.live`, you should use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.commenttext', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
        comment($(this));
    }
});
```

Instead of `document`, you should use the closest parent (this element needs to not be removed from the DOM though, if it's removed, the events are removed too).

P.S. `e.which` is normalized in jQuery, meaning it does `e.keyCode || e.which` for you.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: ok the textarea for the posts is in the div #postDiv, so it should be $('#postDiv').on() right?

Comment: ok I have added the code as you said (see question edit) and it posts fine, but it doesn't add functionality... is there maybe an alternative?

Comment: @Dennis: What exactly is `#posttext`?

Comment: #posttext is the textarea where you can type in a post and on enter key submit it

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I suspect this...should...work?

```
$('.commenttext').live('keyup', function(e) {
  if (((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) && !event.shiftKey) {
    comment($(this));
  }
});
```